# Office Add-in Not Detecting 'en-gb' Locale in Outlook Desktop

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, office-store

I've been having an issue with locale overriding in my Outlook Add-in. I recently added some simple override logic to the manifest to point the user to our UK sign in process if they are in a UK locale. For example:

```html
<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://our-url.com/assets/outlook.html">
        <Override Locale="en-gb" Value="https://our-url.co.uk/assets/outlook.html" />
</SourceLocation>
```

This works correctly in outlook web, so the overrides appear to be implemented correctly. All the urls are the UK versions when I change my language to English(United Kingdom). However it does not work in Outlook desktop. It's picking up the locale as en-us regardless of any settings I change in Outlook or on my PC. We've also had an internal user located in the UK attempt to use the add-in and they still see the US version in Outlook desktop.

Edit: I'm on Windows 7 with Outlook 2016 (Also tested on Windows 10 with Outlook 2016). I've tried setting the editing language under Outlook's options menu to English (United Kingdom) as well as changing the date format, location, key board language, and system locale under the Windows control panel to English (United Kingdom) and changing the Outlook display language settings to match Microsoft Windows. There doesn't seem to be any variants of the english display language pack for Outlook. Just one general english pack.

What setting specifically is checked by Outlook desktop to determine locale?

Comment: Which language setting have you changed? As far as i know, the one to change would be File -> options -> language -> display language. But there on my system I cannot even chose between different English variations.
Have you tried to use any other language to see whether it doesn't work at all or only for this specific locale? For me there is on

Comment: @Developer Updated to list off the settings we've tried.

Comment: Do you have any other Override Locale or DefaultLocale defined? As per the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/localization#examples), you could run into issues with multiple definitions.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT We have two locales in the manifest. The only default locale is en-us and the only override locale is en-gb.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is, that there is only one English display language. You could try to use another locale which has an own display language temporarily just to verify this, but even if that's the cause I have no idea how to fix this right now

Comment: Could you please provide manifest file to us for further investigation?